# Error in meta_query not get result

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have this `WP_Query`

```
<?php
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'banner',
        'posts_per_page' => 25 ,
        'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => 'AND',
        array('key' => 'ads_status','value' => '1'),
        array('key' => 'adsposition','value' => 'top'))
        );
        $slide = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $slide->have_posts() ) : while ( $slide->have_posts() ) : $slide->the_post();  
    $yourfile = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'yourfile', true);  
    $adsposition = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'adsposition', true ); ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $yourfile; ?>" width="1350" height="515">
    <?php
endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I have tow meta box (ads_status,adsposition) and its saved good in wp-admin, but in home page not show any result, but when delete `meta_query`, Its work and get me result.

Where the error ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to be fine and it should work. It's not returning result probably because you are missing `type` parameter for `ads_status` field.

So your code should be.

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type'   => 'banner',
  'posts_per_page' => 25,
  'meta_query'  => array(
    'relation'  => 'AND',
    array(
      'key'     => 'ads_status',
      'value'   => '1',
      'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
    array(
      'key'     => 'adsposition',
      'value'   => 'top',
    ),
  ),
);
$slide = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $slide->have_posts() ) : while ( $slide->have_posts() ) : $slide->the_post();  
$yourfile = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'yourfile', true);  
$adsposition = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'adsposition', true ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $yourfile; ?>" width="1350" height="515">
<?php
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```